# Lucene demo comes with .class files. how to convert it to java files

Tags: java, lucene

I am an absolute beginner in java.
I wanted to know how to convert the .class files in the lucene demo and i want to use the java version.
HOW SHOULD I DO THIS.
please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.class` file is compiled `.java`, just like `.exe` is compiled, e.g., `.cpp`. You can reverse by the process by using Java decompiler. However I'm pretty sure source code is also available, since Lucene is open source.

Which classes do you want to see? Most likely you'll find them in maven repositories or in [source control repository of Lucene](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/).

Comment: when i copy the demo source code into eclipse, i dont get to see any of the files and cant open it

Answer (score 0):

To decompile java class files, you can use [JAD Decompiler](http://www.varaneckas.com/jad/)

If you don't like working with command prompt you can use [DJ Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html)

JAD is available for a lot of OSes, DJ is Windows-only

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have downloaded the code for this lucene demo, opened the project in Eclipse, and the demo uses the lucene library.

Of course this library uses the compiled classes, but you don't need to decompile them. You need to download the source code from lucene site that matches the library version (for instance, 3.6 or 4.0). Then in Eclipse when you go to project properties, libraries section (I think it's inside Build Path) you can add a folder that contains the source code for the desired library (in this case, the lucene jar). Once that is done, if you open a Lucene class you will see the associated Java source file.